# Count number of episodes that has a hash

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like some help with a sql query, i'm using SQLAlchemy but I don't even understand how i can express the query in raw sql.

Im phashing every frames of all videos in a season and adding them to the db.
My goal is to find intros the videos checking for the same reaccuring frames in the videos.

My table looks like:

```
|id|tvdbid|hash |season|episode|offset
---+------+-----+------+-------+------
|1 |1337  |a1a1a|1     |1      |42
---+------+-----+------+-------+-------
|2 |1337  |a1a1a|1     |1      |68
---+------+-----+------+-------+-------
|3 |1337  |a1a1b|1     |2      |92
---+------+-----+------+-------+-------
|4 |1337  |a1a1a|1     |2      |116
---+------+-----+------+-------+-------
|5 |1337  |a1a1a|1     |3      |42
---+------+-----+------+-------+-------
|6 |1337  |a1a1a|1     |3      |42
```

The result im looking for a is a list of rows where the hash matches in n number of episodes(it can only match on episode at the time) and has the same tvdbid and season number.

At the moment i'm doing:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa 
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Hashes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'hashes'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    season = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    episode = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    tvdbid = sa.Column(sa.Text(length=100))
    hash = sa.Column(sa.Text(length=16))
    offset = sa.Column(sa.Integer)

h = Hashes.__table__ 

async def some_web_request(request):

    # I need to use raw sql or core as the db library requires it.
    # my cli tool uses a sync method to insert the rows in the db.
    query = h.select().where(sa.and_(h.c.tvdbid == 
                                     request.path_params['tvdbid'], 
                                     h.c.season == request.path_params['season'])).group_by('hash', 'episode')
    result = await DB.fetch_all(query)
    return result
```

This seems to work just fine, but it isn't exactly what I want so I have to clean up up with python and it will not be viable in the long run. The table will have have between 5 - 500 million rows.

My current "work around":

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def clean_up(result):
    d = defaultdict(set)
    for row in result:
        d[row.hash].add(row.episode)

    final_result = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if (l) > 4: # 4 is the number of episodes.
           final_result.append(k)

    return final_result
```

The desired output should have been:

```
|id|tvdbid|hash |season|episode|offset
---+------+-----+------+-------+------
|1 |1337  |a1a1a|1     |1      |42
```

as the hash needs to present in atleast 50% of the episodes.
or it could simply be a1a1a i dont really need to entire rows now. (this will needed laster to check for recaps etc.)

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't understand your data well, but wouldn't it be enough to just `SELECT DISTINCT` ? Or rather make a `SELECT DISTINCT` out of your `SELECT` results ?

Comment: could you please update the question by adding some more rows of sample data & the desired result. That would help in understanding the problem better

Comment: I have updated what im trying to do, with more sample data and the desired output. Thanks!